# Computing the Joint probablity from condtional probablities

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have a joint probability table of $X and Y$ with
$P(X=1)= 0.325 $
the computations for $P(Y|X=1)$ as :
$P(Y|X=1)= \frac{P(X=1,Y)}{P(X=1)}$
and for Y = 0
$P(Y=0|X=1) = 0.3846153846153846$
and for Y =1
$P(Y=1|X=1) = 0.6153846153846154$
which sum up to one, $ P(Y=0|X=1) + P(Y=1|X=1) = 1$

Similarly, I have another joint probability table of $X and Z$ with
$P(X=1)= 0.5 $
the computations for $P(Y|X=1)$ as :
$P(Z|X=1)= \frac{P(X=1,Z)}{P(X=1)}$

and for Z = 0
$P(Z=0|X=1) = 0.6$

and for Z =1
$P(Z=1|X=1) = 0.4$
which sum up to one , $ P(Z=0|X=1) + P(Z=1|X=1) = 1$

I am trying to compute the the joint probability of $P(X=1,Y,Z)$
however, I am running into an issue that when I sum up all possible combinations of Y and Z of this joint probability, it does not sum up to one. I computed it as  :

$P(X=1,Y,Z)= P(Y|X=1)P(Z|X=1)P(X=1)$

I tried with $P(X=1)= 0.325 $ from the first table and with  $P(X=1)= 0.5 $ from the second table. I also tried as :

$P(X=1,Y,Z)= P(Y|X=1)P(Z|X=1)$

and it does not sum up to 1

Comment: Since $\underbrace{P(X-1)}_{\text{first}}\neq \underbrace{P(X=1)}_{\text{second}}$ the $X$ from each table are clearly not the same thing.

Comment: Even if they were, the factorisation of $P(Y{\,=\,}y, Z{\,=\,}z\mid X{\,=\,}x)=P(Y{\,=\,}y\mid X{\,=\,}x)P(Z{\,=\,}z\mid X{\,=\,}x)$ only occurs when $Y$ and $Z$ are conditionally independent given $X$.